# Android Saving debit/credit card details in database

Tags: android, sqlite, security, e-commerce

I was wondering how big e-commerce players like Flipkart and Paytm saves users debit/credit card information in a database. I know it would not be simple plain text so that anyone with a little programming background can reach. I was curious to know whether they store it in an online database only or they do save it in mobiles internal database(SQLite) also.If yes which encryption mechanism is generally used to store such an important details of the user. Is any special permission from any authority is required to do so?
Thanks.

Comment: If i would be up to this i would look into AES encryption.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Firstly,** you can look at Apple's privacy [overview](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203027). You can see that

> When you add a credit, debit card, or prepaid card to Apple Pay, the information that you enter on your device by typing or using the iSight camera is encrypted and sent to Apple servers.

This is an overview from Apple. The same technique is adopted by other leading companies to protect user data safely.

Storing credentials in the internal storage is highly condemned. **DO NOT** store data in the internal storage.

**Secondly,** as far as the encryption algorithm is concerned then

> In PCI, AES, Triple-DES, SHA-1, RSA etc. are fairly common. PCI is bit slow to adopt new cryptographic standards. This is for part that payment industry uses devices (like cards) with relatively underpowered processing units.

AES is used mostly but the encryption technique varies with time and better and more secure *versions* are used for stronger security. In fact more that one algorithm is used in conjunction for better ciphering of data.

**Lastly,**

`Is any special permission from any authority is required to do so.`

No. You don't need any special permission for encryption and storage as long as you know what you are doing with those sensitive data.

Comment: "You don't need any special permission for encryption and storage as long as you know what you are doing with those sensitive data." - this is wrong. If you're storing card data - which the OP is asking about - and are not storing it in a PCI compliant way you open yourself to huge liability. Some states in the US (like Nevada or Minnesota) have even enacted laws that require you to be PCI compliant to store data. You should consult your payment processor in whatever country you are to determine what restrictions might apply to you.